# Function template overloading on r-value and l-value references

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, rvalue-reference, type-deduction

In c++ primer about "reference collapsing" "overloading function template on r-values and l-values" it is said:

```
template <typename T> void f(T&&); // binds to nonconst rvalues
template <typename T> void f(const T&); // lvalues and const rvalues
```

"As with nontemplate functions, the first version will bind to modifiable rvalues and the
second to lvalues or to const rvalues."

The example is from the book but what I think is a bit different:

The first version will bind to modifiable r-values and modifiable l-values:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T&& x)
{
    cout << "foo(T &&)\n";
}

template <typename T>
void foo(T const& x)
{
    cout << "foo(T const&)\n";
}


int main()
{

    int i = 21;
    int const ic = i;
    foo(5); // foo(int&&)
    foo(i); // foo(int&& ) -> new instantiation foo(int& x) --- here
    foo(ic); // foo(int const&)
    foo(std::move(i)); // foo(int&&)
    foo(std::move(ic));// foo(&&) -> foo(int const&&)


    cout << "\ndone!\n";
}
```

As you can see when I pass `i` which is a modifiable l-value then `foo(int&&)` is called not `foo(int const&)` that is the compiler will apply reference collapsing yielding in instantiating a version of foo this way:

```
 void foo(int& x){}; // after reference collapsing
```

So the version taking a reference to const l-value is preferred only if the argument is a constant l-value or const r-value. (overload resolution and function matching)

That is what I think. What do you think? Thank you!

Comment: `template <typename T> void f(T&&);` is a forwarding reference and binds to everything.

Comment: @bolov: Yes that is it.

Comment: @bolov: But if the argument is const - either l-value or -value then the one with `T const&` is best match. Is it correct?